# Сортировка статей по двум полям

Tags: mysql, sql

Добрый день! Возникла проблема с сортировкой полей, не знаю как ее решить.

Имеются следующие таблицы:

таблица blog:

```
+---------+-------+------------+-------+
| id_blog | title | updated    |  ...  |
+---------+-------+------------+-------+
```

таблица blog_rating:

```
+----------------+------------+------------+
| id_blog_rating | code_blog  | ip_adress  | 
+----------------+------------+------------+
```

Связь между таблицами один-ко-многим по полям `id_blog = code_blog`.
Как превратить нижестоящий запрос в такой, чтобы в нем сортировка шла по полю updated и по количеству записей из таблицы blog_rating, c учетом условия `id_blog` = `code_blog`?

Пока запрос выглядит так:

```
Select * from blog ORDER BY updates DESC LIMIT 1, 10;
```

Comment: Почитайте про оператор JOIN

Answer (score 1):

Вот так. Советую все же почитать мануал, для лучшего понимания сути происходящего.

```
SELECT b.*
FROM blog b
INNER JOIN (SELECT code_blog, count(*) cnt
            FROM blog_rating
            GROUP BY code_blog) br ON b.id_blog = br.code_blog
ORDER BY b.updated, br.cnt
```

Comment: JOIN в принципе знаю. Не мог просто сообразить как это сделать. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: что-то все равно не фурычит запрос...

Comment: Чуть конкретики можно? Что именно не работает? Выдает не те данные? Не в том виде? Может быть, вообще ничего не выдает? Быть может, есть какие-то ошибки? Не скупитесь на подробности и вам всегда помогут. ;)